# on-mouseover not applying on first hover angular 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular5

I have 3 angular tabs. Used [this](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/examples). In second tabs I wrote below html for showing div on hover where hover effect will be apply on hovering `.plus`. but what is happening now the hover effect is not applying on first time and also if I hovered again the div will be show. and also how can I show `roll-over` of hovered element. Now all `roll-over` are showing.

```
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 adv-gal">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="assets/images/On-Screen.jpg">
    <span on-mouseover='over()' class="plus">+</span>
    <p class="without-rol">ON-SCREEN</p>
    <div class="roll-over">
      <h4>Restroom/washroom branding</h4>
      <p class="minus">__</p>
      <span class="line">______________</span>
      <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text,</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and in ts file

```
   over(){

    $(".plus").mouseover(function(){
        $(".roll-over").css("display", "block");
        $(this).
    });
    $(".minus").click(function(){
        $(".roll-over").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jQuery, you can simply call angular mouseover method

Comment: I'm beginner to angular thats why. I used on-mouseover='over()' in html

Comment: why are you mixing angular with jquery ? are you mad

Comment: nah..I'm new to angular.. thats why used jquery

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `mouseover` event from HTML and in a method you are again checking the same so first of remove that code and also you need to remove `.minus` code from there as it will never call so you code will looks like -

```
over(){
    $(".roll-over").css("display", "block");

    // this is not right place for this you can adjust accordingly
    $(".minus").click(() => {
        $(".roll-over").css("display", "none");
    });
}
```

PS: Using JQuery is never recommended with Angular so try to avoid it.

Comment: Yes..working. how can i show only .roll-over hovered plus..because i have multiple divs with same classes..these divs will be dynamic coming from api..

Comment: Can u please suggest any example how can i do this in angular ?

Comment: Actually I have multiple .adv-gal if you check in html... If i hovered any .plus of .adv-gal then all others .adv-gal .roll-over will showing.